# How to make a Notification Activity to save Notifications in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for my App -

1. I have seen many apps like Youtube, Paytm using a bell icon in their app **notification** [Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY2MJ.jpg), and all the notifications that they push are saved inside the **app** notification panel.
2. I also want to **make** the same panel like this what **approach** should I use.

Comment: You can use recycler view for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can Create a database and whenever a notification is received just save the data in DB and retrieve it back when the notification activity is called.